# Does "Click _Use system git_Check" in gitconfig mean anything?

Tags: git

My global .gitconfig had somehow got the following line under [core]:

```
excludesfile = Click _Use system git_Check \"C:\\Users\\Adam.Conway\\gitignore_global.txt\"
```

*Does the `Click _Use system git_Check` part mean anything?  If so, what does it do?*

Background: Eclipse complained about invalid character on the colon. Deleting the line and running a new `git config --global core.excludesfile` command reset it to being just a path and eclipse stopped complaining.  But I can't find much about the rest and why it might have been there.

I'm running on windows.  I mainly use a combination of command line (git for windows) and SourceTree, but have also isntalled and played with Tortoise Git and Git Extensions so could have come from any of the above.

Comment: Looks like a result of bad copy/paste. Shouldn't be there at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of [`core.excludesFile`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coreexcludesFile) should be a string. It is the path to the global [`gitignore file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

The `Click _Use system git_Check` fragment doesn't mean anything and it should not be there. It was added (most probably by mistake) by one of the Git interfaces you use.

It could be a proprietary settings added by some of them but it looks more like a localization identifier that sneaked somehow in a place where it shouldn't be.

Many Git GUI interfaces add proprietary settings in the global Git configuration file but the correct way to do it is to use [separate sections (and subsections, if needed)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_syntax).

Since you have already found the fix I would not worry about it any more.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought/hoped that was the case, but wanted to confirm.